# why is my for loop function in r not working (trying to truncate outliers in the dataset)

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to replace extreme values with the nearest value in the dataset. I know the ifelse () works better, but just wondering why is the for loop not working.

```
truncate <- function(a){
  m <- mean(a)
  sd <- sd(a)
  up <- m+3*sd
  low <- m-3*sd
  a1 <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(a)){
    if (a[i] > up) {
      a1[i] = up
      }
    if (a[i] < low){
      a1[i] = low
      }
    else {
      a1[i] = a[i]
    }
    }
  return (a1)
  } 
a <- c(1:100)
```

Answer (score 2):

The for-loop is working correctly and iterating through the elements of `1:length(a)`.  I am assuming you are giving `a <- c(1:100)` as an input to `truncate()` and you say your function isn't working because it just returns the same value as `a`.  This seems to be because, using `a` as input, `up` results in `137.5345` and `low` results in `-36.53448`.  No values are greater than `up` or less than `low`, thus only the `else` statement is reached.

Also, the copy-and-append pattern you are using to generate `a1` in your for-loop and conditional statements is computationally expensive.  It can be vectorized and the function can be made more efficient as follows:

```
truncate <- function(a) {
    m <- mean(a)
    sd <- sd(a)
    up <- m+3*sd
    low <- m-3*sd
    a[a > up] <- up
    a[a < low] <- low
    a
}
```